# Запустить другое окно из Main

Tags: java, javafx

Есть класс который запускает окно: (он работает, т.е. при запуске открывается окно в котором я могу работать)

```
public class Start extends Application{

        @Override
        public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
            String fxmlFile = "fxml/sample.fxml";
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            Parent root = (Parent) loader.load(getClass().getResourceAsStream(fxmlFile));
            stage.setTitle("JavaFX");

            stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
            stage.show();
        }
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            launch(args);
        }

    }
```

Класс из которого я хочу запустить окно

```
public class Main{
     public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
          //Здесь я хочу запустить то окно при определенных условиях.
          Stage stage = new Stage()
          String fxmlFile = "fxml/sample.fxml";
          FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
          Parent root = (Parent) 
          loader.load(getClass().getResourceAsStream(fxmlFile));
          stage.setTitle("JavaFX");

          stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
          stage.show();

}
     }
```

Выдает ошибку:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError  at
>   javafx.stage.Window.(Window.java:1191)  at
>   javafx.stage.Stage.(Stage.java:239)     at
>   javafx.stage.Stage.(Stage.java:227)     at Main.main(Main.java:82)
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This operation is
>   permitted on the event thread only; currentThread = main  at
>   com.sun.glass.ui.Application.checkEventThread(Application.java:443)
>     at com.sun.glass.ui.Screen.setEventHandler(Screen.java:285)     at
>   com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.setScreenConfigurationListener(QuantumToolkit.java:667)
>     at javafx.stage.Screen.(Screen.java:79)     ... 4 more

Прерывается на строчке Stage stage = new Stage()

Как мне запустить окно из Main? Рассматриваю любые способы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2-й класс не запустится, так как Stage создается автоматически после вызова launch();. Нужно либо оставить все так как есть в первом классе, либо из метода main в другом классе вызвать метод launch(); для класса наследующего Application то есть написать так: Start.launch();